# Keras predict/predict_on_batch giving different answers than predict_step/__call__()

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, keras-2

From my understanding, all four of these methods:
`predict`, `predict_on_batch`, `predict_step`, and a direct forward pass through the model (e.g. `model(x, training=False)` or `__call__()`)
should all give the same results, some are just more efficient than others in how they handle batches of data versus one sample.

But I am actually getting different results on an image super-resolution (upscaling) task I'm working on:

```
for lowres, _ in val.take(1):
    # Get a randomly cropped region of the lowres image for upscaling
    lowres = tf.image.random_crop(lowres, (150, 150, 3))  # uint8
    
    # Need to add a dummy batch dimension for the predict step    
    model_inputs = tf.expand_dims(lowres, axis=0)  # (1, 150, 150, 3), uint8
    
    # And convert the uint8 image values to float32 for input to the model
    model_inputs = tf.cast(model_inputs, tf.float32)  # float32
    
    preds = model.predict_on_batch(model_inputs)
    min_val = tf.reduce_min(preds).numpy()
    max_val = tf.reduce_max(preds).numpy()
    print("Min value: ", min_val)
    print("Max value: ", max_val)
    
    preds = model.predict(model_inputs)
    min_val = tf.reduce_min(preds).numpy()
    max_val = tf.reduce_max(preds).numpy()
    print("Min value: ", min_val)
    print("Max value: ", max_val)
    
    preds = model.predict_step(model_inputs)
    min_val = tf.reduce_min(preds).numpy()
    max_val = tf.reduce_max(preds).numpy()
    print("Min value: ", min_val)
    print("Max value: ", max_val)
    
    preds = model(model_inputs, training=False)  # __call__()
    min_val = tf.reduce_min(preds).numpy()
    max_val = tf.reduce_max(preds).numpy()
    print("Min value: ", min_val)
    print("Max value: ", max_val)
```

Prints:

```
Min value:  -6003.622
Max value:  5802.6826

Min value:  -6003.622
Max value:  5802.6826

Min value:  -53.7696
Max value:  315.1499

Min value:  -53.7696
Max value:  315.1499
```

Both `predict_step` and `__call__()` give the "correct" answers as defined by the upscaled images look correct.

I'm happy to share more details on the model if that's helpful, but for now I thought I'd just leave it at this to not overcomplicate the question.  At first I wondered if these methods had different results based on training/inference modes, but my model doesn't use any `BatchNorm` or `Dropout` layers, so that shouldn't make a difference here.  It's completely composed of: `Conv2D`, `Add`, `tf.nn.depth_to_space` (pixel shuffle), and `Rescaling` layers.  That's it.  It also doesn't use any subclassing or override any methods, just uses `keras.Model(inputs, outputs)`.

Any ideas why these prediction methods would give different answers?

**EDIT:**
I've been able to create a minimally reproducible example where you can see the issue.  Please see: https://www.kaggle.com/code/quackaddict7/really-minimum-reproducible-example

I initially couldn't reproduce the problem in a minimal example.  I eventually added back in a dataset, batching, data augmentation, training, model file saving/restoring, and eventually discovered **the issue is GPU vs. CPU!**  So I took all that back out for my minimal example.  If you run the notebook attached you'll see that on CPU, all four methods give the same answer with randomly initialized weights.  But if you change to P100 GPU, `predict`/`predict_on_batch` differ from `predict_step`/forward pass (`__call__`).

So I guess at this point, my question is, why are CPU vs. GPU results different here?

Comment: Just take sneak peak, you're using random_crop, so doesn't that give random singnal to the model? However, if possible, could you please add a reproducible code? Otherwise any answer would be based on assumption and possibly leads to downvote.

Comment: @Innat I use a random crop but just once and reuse that same image for the prediction in all different methods.  I'd still like to not overload people with the whole code, the question is mostly, shouldn't all these methods give the same answer when run on the same input X?

Comment: Actually, I was not asking to share the whole code but sample code that reproduce output discrepancy you faced. I have tested predict, predict_on_batch, call, predict_step, all give same results. And clearly answering with this, won't help you, thus required some sample code from your end.

Comment: @Innat  Thanks, I understand.  I initially tried creating a minimum reproducible example for you, but then I couldn't reproduce the issue!  I've now spent all morning creating one and finally was able to reproduce it.  Please see my edited answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested the given sample code in `tf.keras==2.12.0` and found a possible bug in the API and it fails only on GPU. In your sample code, the mismatch occurred due to the `relu` activation. If we set anything else, i.e. `selu` or `elu` or even `leaky_relu`,  they would work as expected.

```py
def ResBlock(inputs):
    x = layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding="same")(inputs)
    x = layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding="same")(x)
    x = layers.Add()([inputs, x])
    return x
```

In order to keep using `relu` method, following fix can be adopted for the moment.

```py
def relu(x):
    return keras.backend.maximum(x, 0)

def ResBlock(inputs):
    x = layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding="same")(inputs)
    x = keras.layers.Lambda(relu, output_shape=lambda shape: shape)(x)
    x = layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding="same")(x)
    x = layers.Add()([inputs, x])
    return x
```

Here is the full code for references.

**Model**

```py
def relu(x):
    return keras.backend.maximum(x, 0)

def ResBlock(inputs):
    x = layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding="same")(inputs)
    x = keras.layers.Lambda(
        relu, output_shape=lambda shape: shape
    )(x)
    x = layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding="same")(x)
    x = layers.Add()([inputs, x])
    return x

def Upsampling(inputs, factor=2, **kwargs):
    x = layers.Conv2D(
        64 * (factor ** 2), 3, padding="same", **kwargs
    )(inputs)
    x = tf.nn.depth_to_space(x, block_size=factor)
    x = layers.Conv2D(
        64 * (factor ** 2), 3, padding="same", **kwargs
    )(x)
    x = tf.nn.depth_to_space(x, block_size=factor)
    return x
```

```py
def make_model(num_filters, num_of_residual_blocks):
    input_layer = layers.Input(shape=(None, None, 3))
    x = layers.Rescaling(scale=1.0 / 255)(input_layer)
    x = x_new = layers.Conv2D(num_filters, 3, padding="same")(x)

    for i in range(num_of_residual_blocks):
        x_new = ResBlock(x_new)

    x_new = layers.Conv2D(num_filters, 3, padding="same")(x_new)
    x = layers.Add()([x, x_new])
    x = Upsampling(x)
    x = layers.Conv2D(3, 3, padding="same")(x)
    
    output_layer = layers.Rescaling(scale=255)(x)
    return keras.Model(input_layer, output_layer)
```

**Inference**

```py
lowres = tf.random.uniform(
    shape=(150, 150, 3), 
    minval=0, 
    maxval=256, 
    dtype='float32'
)
model_inputs = tf.expand_dims(lowres, axis=0)

predict_out = model.predict(model_inputs)
predict_on_batch_out = model.predict_on_batch(model_inputs)
predict_call_out = model(model_inputs, training=False).numpy()
predict_step_out = model.predict_step(model_inputs).numpy()
print(
    predict_out.shape, 
    predict_on_batch_out.shape, 
    predict_call_out.shape, 
    predict_step_out.shape
)
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 1s/step
(1, 600, 600, 3) (1, 600, 600, 3) (1, 600, 600, 3) (1, 600, 600, 3)
```

**Logits Checking**

```py
# OK
np.testing.assert_allclose(
    predict_out,
    predict_on_batch_out,
    1e-5, 1e-5
)

# OK
np.testing.assert_allclose(
    predict_on_batch_out,
    predict_call_out,
    1e-5, 1e-5
)

# OK
np.testing.assert_allclose(
    predict_call_out,
    predict_step_out,
    1e-5, 1e-5
)
```

Comment: I saw you posted in [github](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/19403), so, if it's the case to your real codebase, report to the keras-team about it. Note, they might ask you to run in keras 3.

Comment: thanks for your reply.  Sorry, I'm not sure what you're saying though.  Didn't I essentially already report it to keras-team by filing a bug there?  It's surprising that there might be an issue with ReLU given how old and well-tested that function is.

Comment: As of today, this example can't be ported to Keras 3 because of the tf.nn.depth_to_space() functions.  I read the Keras 2 to 3 porting guide and it says "using a TF op on a Keras tensor during functional model construction is disallowed, use an equivalent op from keras.ops." but the depth_to_space() function isn't in keras.ops.  I'm considering porting it myself to try contributing to this wonderful library, but I'm not sure if that'd be too meaty for my first contribution.  :-)

Comment: Thank you for digging in with me and finding the potential root cause.  I'll mark this answer resolved, but should you be on the GitHub ticket?